# Inverse Kinematics: Bones doesn't bend towards the pole target

Tags: rigging, bones, pose-mode, inverse-kinematics

I am doing my first rigging in Blender. I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XkiWBSSuxLw) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-2v_CKmVE8) youtube videos.

My armature looks like this from the front view:
[image]

When I move the inverse kinematics "target bone" up in the z-axis, it moves like seen in the screen shot below. I want the knee to move directly towards to the "pole target", but instead it slightly strays away from it.
[image]

My inverse kinematics settings are like this:
[image]

My copy constraint settings are like this:
[image]

How do I make the knee bend towards strictly to the forward direction where the target bone resides?

Edit: [This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1atOi5MzAzAggokj7kSEBBeh1MhQkiKiK/view?usp=sharing) is my current design file.

Comment: maybe bend your knee a bit forward in Edit mode? If it still doesn't work please share your file

Comment: I agree with moonboots. There's another very recent YT video on leg IK rigging [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DkIbCmdlYT4)

Comment: @moonboots I had already bent it a little bit in the forward direction. I also edited my question and added the design file at the end of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to slightly bend the knee forwards, and also the pole target in order to move it a bit away from the knee:

[image]

It seems to work:

[image]

Comment: I has already bent the knee in the forward direction, but after your message I bent it even more and moved the pole even further away. Now it works, thank your.  
But I still don't understand the reason why it didn't work first time. I thought bending the knee just a little bit was enough to tell Blender how to solve the IK problem. I also thought that the direction of the reference pole was important but not its distance from the bone object.

Comment: I can't tell exactly why it wouldn't work in the first place. For the pole target, the distance doesn't count, it's just that you need to make sure that the pole will still be in front of the knee when you'll bend it